# Cannot create a new AVD using Java Eclipse ADT

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a new device and I filled out the options accurately. However, the `create device` button won't do anything after I click on it.

I am relatively new to Eclipse and I am simply following the instructions of a book; can anybody help me create this device? I do not believe this has to do with computer speed.

(I can't post a picture because I don't have enough reputation, I just made an account.)

Comment: Please post link with photo I will add it in for you

Answer (score 1):

Ok what you can do is to check the Image of emulator when you creating it!Check does it compatible with the device name your trying to create.Try different images.Mainly the problem is in image when trying to create.BUT i would not advise you to use emulator of eclipse.Its very slow and not useful for google developments instead you could use the emulator which is the best in world for my opinion here is the link

> https://www.genymotion.com/#!/